# Как изменить имя всех инстанция переменной в Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, рефакторинг

Я делаю очистку кода скриптов. Хочу заменить имена некоторых переменных для более высокой читабельности кода.

В развитых IDE есть такие функции типа "Refactor", с помощью которой можно сменить имя всех инстанции переменной в тексте. Есть ли такая функция в Notepad++?

Comment: Есть ли в текстовом редакторе функция поиска и замены текста... Конечно, на то он и *редактор*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения за беспокойство.Нашел ответ на английском сайте superuser.com: https://superuser.com/questions/621986/editing-all-instances-of-a-string-in-notepad

Ответ - CTRL+H.

Не буду удалять вопрос. Пусть в рунете тоже будет ответ на него.

Comment: Нашел небольшой недочет/отличие от Refactor. Если имя переменной является частью второй переменной, то вторая тоже измениться при замене первой с помощью CTRL + H. Например, $hello и $helloworld изменятся оба при замене слова "hello".